# How to create configurable build using react and webpack?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I have a js file which contains all configurations like port, domain, API URLs and other URLs.
I created bundled with webpack and deployed with express server (app.use(express.static("build"))) on staging environment (as given in below image).
Now I came to a situation where client can deploy the application, so client only know the all configuration and I want to share only build folder with client not whole code.

[image]

Is there any way to do change in configuration after build or any other solution?

Comment: Well, port, domain, API URLs and other URLs all needs to be configured by backend i.e. the hosting environment. What config you wanna change in build?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh Port, domain & URLs only configured by the client, I don't have these details.